# DJANGO calling another user's profile

Tags: django, profile

I am familiar with calling the currently logged in user, using: requestcontext, user, and get_profile.
What if I am creating another page, not of the currently logged in user?

my url is:

```
r'^/profile/(\w+)/$'
```

and view is as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def profile(request, username):
    person = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    return render_to_response('profile.html', {"person":person}, 
         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my template, I can enter {{user.username}} or {{user.get_profile.name}} and get values, but not {{person.username}} or {{person.get_profile.name}}. What is a way that I can retrieve the information I need? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter` returns a list, even if it just has one match. Since you're looking for exactly one username, use `.get(username=username)`, and your person will end up with just the one object.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Retrieving objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) on Django's documentation. Methods that returns QuerySets:

**Method .all()**

> The all() method returns a QuerySet of all the objects in the
>   database.

```
>> users = User.objects.all()
>> type(users) # This is a QuerySet, not a User object
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

**Method .filter() and exclude()**

> **filter(**kwargs)** 
>   Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match
>   the given lookup parameters.
>
> **exclude(**kwargs)** 
>   Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that do not match the given lookup parameters.

```
>> users = User.objects.filter(username=username)
>> type(users) # This is a QuerySet, not a User object
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>

>> users = User.objects.exclude(username=username)
>> type(users) # This is a QuerySet, not a User object
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

---

Now, if you take a look at [Methods that do not return QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets).

This is what you need to use:

**Method .get()**

> **get(**kwargs)** 
>   Returns the object matching the given lookup parameters, which should be in the format described in Field lookups.

```
>> users = User.objects.exclude(username=username)
>> type(users) # This is a User object
<class 'YourProject.YourApp.models.User'>
```